# Ruby/C/Makefile, what is the default pcap.h file that is used in -lpcap/#include <pcap.h>

Tags: c, ruby, makefile, pcap, libpcap

How can I determine what pcap.h file is being included in a C source that is being compiled/installed via a Makefile?

Specifically, it is a Ruby library (pcaprub) that is being installed via:

```
ruby extconf.rb && make && make install
```

and the extconf.rb is:

```
require 'mkmf'

if /i386-mswin32/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM
    pcap_dir        = with_config("pcap-dir", "C:\WpdPack")
    pcap_includedir = with_config("pcap-includedir", pcap_dir + "\\include")
    pcap_libdir     = with_config("pcap-libdir", pcap_dir + "\\lib")

    $CFLAGS  = "-DWIN32 -I#{pcap_includedir}"
    $LDFLAGS = "/link /LIBPATH:#{pcap_libdir}"
    have_library("wpcap", "pcap_open_live")
    have_library("wpcap", "pcap_setnonblock")
else
    have_library("pcap", "pcap_open_live")
    have_library("pcap", "pcap_setnonblock")
end

if ( RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/ )
    $CFLAGS += " -DRUBY_19"
end

create_makefile("pcaprub")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the generated `Makefile` to see what `-I` options are being passed to `gcc`? You can also pass `-H` to `gcc` to display the header file that it ends up using:

> ```
>    -H  Print the name of each header file used, in addition to other
>        normal activities.  Each name is indented to show how deep in the
>        #include stack it is.  Precompiled header files are also printed,
>        even if they are found to be invalid; an invalid precompiled header
>        file is printed with ...x and a valid one with ...! .
> ```